# TinyMCE image upload for mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

By default, tinyMCE for mvc has plugin with image insert (with external URL).

Is there any possibility, to choose image from user disc, then upload image and automaticly insert it in editor? (just image upload) - of course, for asp.net MVC.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Either buy the sophisticated tinymce file-manager plugin "moxiemanager" from here
http://www.moxiemanager.com

or use on of these free tinymce image-uploader plugins

http://sourceforge.net/p/tinymce/plugins/